# how to convert a uint32_t array data buffer to an uint8_t array in C?

Tags: stm32, adc, dma, nrf24l01

I'm making a STM32F4 RC transmitter using the NRF24L01, but this device only support a uint8_t buffer array to transmit. I'm using in the ADC (DMA mode) in my STM32 board but the ADC read output is in uint32_t array (0 to 4095).
This is the main.c code that I'm using (I only paste the focus part of the code).

I really appreciate you support.

```
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include"NRF24L01.h"

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
#define NUM_ADC 1
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_adc1;

SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
uint8_t ADC_Buffer[NUM_ADC];

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
uint8_t TxAddress[] = {0xEE,0xDD,0xCC,0xBB,0xAA};
uint8_t TxData[] = "HELLO World\n";

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  NRF24_Init();
  NRF24_TxMode(TxAddress, 10);

  HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t *)ADC_Buffer, NUM_ADC);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      if (NRF24_Transmit(ADC_Buffer) == 1)
          {
              HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_1);
          }
          HAL_Delay(1000);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      /*if (NRF24_Transmit(TxData) == 1)
      {
          HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_1);
      }
      HAL_Delay(1000);*/
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
```

Comment: How do you want to convert the uint32_t array to a uint8_t array? Do you need to  preserve or eliminate the padding bytes?

Comment: My usual method for converting is to use a union for each 32 bit value that maps to 4 bytes, which yields an array of unions.

Comment: @PeterSmith That may work in your specific case of CPU architecture and compiler, but it is implementation defined and generally undefined due to endianness. C++ forbids type punning, C99 allows it. If you are writing code that should work on multiple platforms or multiple compilers, don't use union for this.

Comment: If I needed to use it as a uint8_t array, I might alias a pointer. There are a number of ways to achieve what is required.

Answer (score -1):

`uint8_t NRF24_Transmit (uint8_t *data)` only transmits **one byte**. There is no size, so it cannot transmit an array.

Comment: It depends how `NRF24_Transmit` is implemented. **If** the array is expected to be a zero-terminated string you don't need to provide an array length. I'm looking at the commented out example (`uint8_t TxData[] = "HELLO World\n"; ... NRF24_Transmit(TxData)...`).